# virtual hosts with subdomains not working

Tags: apache

I have these two virtual hosts for my development server. I need to send any request to `dev.` or `*.dev.` to one application, which will handle dealing with the subdomains. Right now, only the second one works, with any request sent to `*.dev.` being passed to the application. But if I just go to the `dev.` subdomain, i get an error in my browser saying the page couldn't be found. What is going on?

```
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName dev.redemptionconnect.com
    ServerAlias dev.redemptionconnect.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/dev.redemptionconnect.com/"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName sub.dev.redemptionconnect.com
    ServerAlias *.dev.redemptionconnect.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/dev.redemptionconnect.com/"
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Please post your VirtualHost config.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit**: I assume you have defined the subdomain `dev.redemptionconnect.com` in DNS? I don't turn up an address for it.

```
# tournaments.dev. works....
PING tournaments.dev.redemptionconnect.com (107.21.224.129) 56(84) bytes of data.

# but bare dev. does not...
ping: unknown host dev.redemptionconnect.com
```

You'll need DNS records for the first subdomain and each of its sub-subdomains.  Defining the sub-subdomains does not implicitly define their parent subdomain as well.

This may be because you are using `dev.redemptionconnect.com` in both the `ServerName and`ServerAlias`directives for the first`VirtualHost`, however I wouldn't expect that to cause an issue.

However, since you're pointing them both to the same application directory do you really need to `VirtualHost`s at all? You can just specify multiple `ServerAlias`:

```
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName sub.dev.redemptionconnect.com
    # Multiple domains in ServerAlias
    ServerAlias dev.redemptionconnect.com *.dev.redemptionconnect.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/dev.redemptionconnect.com/"
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: that doesn't work either. I have set up the dns. If you go to http://tournaments.dev.redemptionconnect.com, you'll see it works.

Comment: @LordZardeck Yes, the subdomain is defined, but the parent `dev.redemptionconnect.com` must also be defined.  When looking it up, I get `ping: unknown host dev.redemptionconnect.com`  Make sure the bare `dev.` domain has an A record or CNAME in your DNS.

Comment: that was it. i'll accept your answer although you should edit it to include needing the TWO dns records. Thanks so much!